# grails: remoteFunction with multiple select

Tags: ajax, grails, select

I need to use the remoteFunction directive with a multiple select.
The select is as follows:

```
<g:select name="receiptItems" from="${myproject.ReceiptItem.list()}"
     multiple="multiple" optionKey="id" optionValue="description" size="5"
     value="${receiptInstance?.receiptItems*.id}" class="many-to-many"
         onchange="${remoteFunction(
            controller: 'Receipt',
            action: 'sumReceiptItems',
            params: '\'receiptItemsSelected=\' + this.value',
            onSuccess: 'updateTotalAmount(\'totalAmount\', data, \'00000\')')}"/>
```

I have the `sumReceiptItems` action in the Receipt controller that takes the parameter `receiptItemsSelected` and use it to update another text field.

The problem is that `this.value` gives me *only one* selected value, that is *the last one selected*. I need to pass to controller all the selected values in the select.
How can I do it?

Thanks for your precious help

Comment: why not send the content of the text field as a param as well? `this.value` will always send the current value that triggered onchange... it won't remember the previous values that were selected

Comment: the text field will be updated with jquery based on receiptItemsSelected value. receiptItemsSelected would store the ids of selected values. In controller, I get related values of each receiptItem(with findAllByIdInList method) and I sum values to show the sum in the text field. Why I need to have text field as param? Is there a way in gsp to get selected values of select?

Answer (score 1):

Just use [jQuery's val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) instead of `this.value`, that will get all the selected items:

```
params: '\'receiptItemsSelected=\' + jQuery(this).val()'
```

Note that you have to import jQuery if you haven't used it in your project yet. You can do that simply using `<r:require module='jquery' />` in the `<head>` section if you are using an up-to-date Grails version.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery to get the values:

```
var selections = new Array();

$("#receiptItems").change(function() {
   var value = $(this).val();
   selections[selections.length] = value;
});
```

You can add the value to a global defined list. In this way you get all the selections.